# Length of a border of a POLYGON (or MULTIPOLYGON) in postgis

Tags: postgresql, gis, geospatial, postgis

I have a PostGIS database with some POLYGONs (some are MULTIPOLYGONs). I want to find the length of the border of these polygons. They are shapes of administrative boundaries, and hence I'd like to get the length of the boundary.

For the MULTIPOLYGON shapes, I'd like it to be the sum of the boundary of each of the POLYGONs that make it up.

Here's an example of 2 of the shapes (the SRID is 900913):

```
POLYGON((-771958.31 6885015.34,-771923.15 6885310.54,-771809.28 6885392.78,-771679.07 6885406.05,-771424.03 6885497.97,-770935.04 6885439.73,-770713.55 6885538.08,-770482.81 6885745.21,-770233.34 6886191.66,-770181.32 6886711.86,-770370.21 6886944.29,-770397.74 6886956.42,-770303.56 6887085.22,-770234.96 6887174.93,-770110.06 6887301.59,-769891.93 6887400.11,-769761.75 6887417.69,-769724.8 6887495.1,-769529.55 6887931.36,-769425.75 6887880.34,-769228.74 6887818.78,-769114.39 6887829.32,-768933.2 6887896.17,-768896.84 6887976.98,-768741.36 6888049.11,-768711.51 6888129.98,-768629.41 6888316.56,-768516.09 6888456.13,-768438.68 6888533.53,-768334.47 6888647.22,-768256.1 6888760.41,-768166.54 6888689.5,-768103.1 6888692.01,-768056.2 6888520.15,-767980.56 6888469.13,-767846.87 6888393.49,-767635.77 6888212.29,-767565.41 6888094.43,-767465.14 6888068.05,-767255.8 6888046.94,-767097.49 6888046.94,-767000.73 6888031.11,-766896.94 6887851.68,-766782.6 6887663.44,-766604.93 6887519.21,-766413.18 6887371.43,-766139.4 6887370.19,-765988.89 6887303.02,-765897.72 6887162.23,-765924.86 6887144.75,-765977.74 6887058.21,-766136.4 6887012.53,-766190.39 6886977.26,-766385.86 6886894.81,-766536.29 6886825.12,-766726.67 6886753.74,-766903.44 6886749.84,-766984.18 6886698.85,-767036.04 6886737.09,-767177.11 6886761.74,-767264.65 6886771.08,-767350.14 6886738.68,-767523.22 6886759.11,-767572.5 6886717.04,-767653.03 6886739.86,-767691.49 6886685.78,-767772.01 6886682.18,-767778.03 6886589.63,-767910.62 6886578.9,-768035.55 6886518.56,-768184.29 6886435.26,-768198.74 6886385.97,-768241.23 6886229.58,-768346.61 6886081.7,-768361.91 6885969.53,-768306.67 6885814.84,-768274.37 6885730.7,-768153.68 6885684.8,-768134.14 6885608.32,-768165.62 6885539.63,-768244.94 6885492.76,-768331.48 6885360.55,-768430.01 6885214.38,-768437.96 6885113.83,-768636.67 6885175.57,-768758.43 6885374.97,-768775.54 6885487.75,-768887.58 6885663.36,-768890.62 6885697.22,-769007.53 6885852.57,-769032.42 6885847.82,-769046.75 6885814.89,-769079.05 6885777.21,-769172.84 6885705.87,-769222.94 6885673.18,-769269.78 6885663.38,-769332.85 6885636.46,-769456.56 6885615.08,-769674.02 6885529.96,-769708.16 6885476.49,-769707.47 6885411.77,-769739.7 6885358.83,-769792.79 6885311.27,-769833.53 6885288.08,-769858.28 6885233.95,-769883.51 6885138.09,-769923.29 6885074.87,-769897.32 6885017.75,-769915.3 6884984.68,-770018.88 6884984.27,-770144.01 6885043.71,-770211.53 6884848.97,-770266.09 6884545.38,-770295.69 6884559.34,-770577.74 6884634.02,-770774.56 6884742.9,-771051.06 6884901.37,-771286.57 6884987.78,-771421.81 6884985.53,-771480.47 6884957.27,-771619.97 6884859.66,-771748.55 6884800.97,-771887.67 6884896.97,-771958.31 6885015.34))
MULTIPOLYGON(((-748402.29 6933642.13,-748200.12 6933723.79,-747125.33 6934322.44,-747080.44 6934234.95,-747015.79 6934158.69,-746940.66 6934083.36,-746869.3 6934016.65,-746810.92 6933906.62,-746778.54 6933811.99,-746718.21 6933728.99,-746628.02 6933648.49,-746546.94 6933494.73,-746397.31 6933370.7,-747345.83 6933019.56,-747417.1 6933252.35,-747583.38 6933428.15,-747668.91 6933432.89,-747801.85 6933366.36,-747906.14 6933234.1,-748173.7 6933683.88,-748399.51 6933622.62,-748402.29 6933642.13)),((-748665.23 6934960.19,-747689.57 6935406.98,-747622.32 6935293.38,-747576.11 6935204.26,-747541.11 6935103.13,-747496.85 6935009.48,-747840.87 6934882.49,-748550.36 6934423.01,-748613.66 6934709.69,-748665.23 6934960.19)))
```

I'm sure there is a PostGIS function for it in this list ( http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/reference.html ), but I'm not sure which.

I would also like this length in metres. I have the same data in a `GEOGRAPHY` (as opposed to the older `GEOMETRY` column type). Is it possible to calculate the border length from that?

Answer (score 3):

Use [ST_Perimeter](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_Perimeter.html) on geography types to return the perimeter of the borders in meters:

```
WITH data AS
(SELECT 1 AS gid, 'SRID=900913;POLYGON((-771958.31 6885015.34,-771923.15 6885310.54,-771809.28 6885392.78,-771679.07 6885406.05,-771424.03 6885497.97,-770935.04 6885439.73,-770713.55 6885538.08,-770482.81 6885745.21,-770233.34 6886191.66,-770181.32 6886711.86,-770370.21 6886944.29,-770397.74 6886956.42,-770303.56 6887085.22,-770234.96 6887174.93,-770110.06 6887301.59,-769891.93 6887400.11,-769761.75 6887417.69,-769724.8 6887495.1,-769529.55 6887931.36,-769425.75 6887880.34,-769228.74 6887818.78,-769114.39 6887829.32,-768933.2 6887896.17,-768896.84 6887976.98,-768741.36 6888049.11,-768711.51 6888129.98,-768629.41 6888316.56,-768516.09 6888456.13,-768438.68 6888533.53,-768334.47 6888647.22,-768256.1 6888760.41,-768166.54 6888689.5,-768103.1 6888692.01,-768056.2 6888520.15,-767980.56 6888469.13,-767846.87 6888393.49,-767635.77 6888212.29,-767565.41 6888094.43,-767465.14 6888068.05,-767255.8 6888046.94,-767097.49 6888046.94,-767000.73 6888031.11,-766896.94 6887851.68,-766782.6 6887663.44,-766604.93 6887519.21,-766413.18 6887371.43,-766139.4 6887370.19,-765988.89 6887303.02,-765897.72 6887162.23,-765924.86 6887144.75,-765977.74 6887058.21,-766136.4 6887012.53,-766190.39 6886977.26,-766385.86 6886894.81,-766536.29 6886825.12,-766726.67 6886753.74,-766903.44 6886749.84,-766984.18 6886698.85,-767036.04 6886737.09,-767177.11 6886761.74,-767264.65 6886771.08,-767350.14 6886738.68,-767523.22 6886759.11,-767572.5 6886717.04,-767653.03 6886739.86,-767691.49 6886685.78,-767772.01 6886682.18,-767778.03 6886589.63,-767910.62 6886578.9,-768035.55 6886518.56,-768184.29 6886435.26,-768198.74 6886385.97,-768241.23 6886229.58,-768346.61 6886081.7,-768361.91 6885969.53,-768306.67 6885814.84,-768274.37 6885730.7,-768153.68 6885684.8,-768134.14 6885608.32,-768165.62 6885539.63,-768244.94 6885492.76,-768331.48 6885360.55,-768430.01 6885214.38,-768437.96 6885113.83,-768636.67 6885175.57,-768758.43 6885374.97,-768775.54 6885487.75,-768887.58 6885663.36,-768890.62 6885697.22,-769007.53 6885852.57,-769032.42 6885847.82,-769046.75 6885814.89,-769079.05 6885777.21,-769172.84 6885705.87,-769222.94 6885673.18,-769269.78 6885663.38,-769332.85 6885636.46,-769456.56 6885615.08,-769674.02 6885529.96,-769708.16 6885476.49,-769707.47 6885411.77,-769739.7 6885358.83,-769792.79 6885311.27,-769833.53 6885288.08,-769858.28 6885233.95,-769883.51 6885138.09,-769923.29 6885074.87,-769897.32 6885017.75,-769915.3 6884984.68,-770018.88 6884984.27,-770144.01 6885043.71,-770211.53 6884848.97,-770266.09 6884545.38,-770295.69 6884559.34,-770577.74 6884634.02,-770774.56 6884742.9,-771051.06 6884901.37,-771286.57 6884987.78,-771421.81 6884985.53,-771480.47 6884957.27,-771619.97 6884859.66,-771748.55 6884800.97,-771887.67 6884896.97,-771958.31 6885015.34))'::geometry AS geom
UNION SELECT 2 AS gid,
'SRID=900913;MULTIPOLYGON(((-748402.29 6933642.13,-748200.12 6933723.79,-747125.33 6934322.44,-747080.44 6934234.95,-747015.79 6934158.69,-746940.66 6934083.36,-746869.3 6934016.65,-746810.92 6933906.62,-746778.54 6933811.99,-746718.21 6933728.99,-746628.02 6933648.49,-746546.94 6933494.73,-746397.31 6933370.7,-747345.83 6933019.56,-747417.1 6933252.35,-747583.38 6933428.15,-747668.91 6933432.89,-747801.85 6933366.36,-747906.14 6933234.1,-748173.7 6933683.88,-748399.51 6933622.62,-748402.29 6933642.13)),((-748665.23 6934960.19,-747689.57 6935406.98,-747622.32 6935293.38,-747576.11 6935204.26,-747541.11 6935103.13,-747496.85 6935009.48,-747840.87 6934882.49,-748550.36 6934423.01,-748613.66 6934709.69,-748665.23 6934960.19)))'::geometry AS geom)

SELECT gid,
    ST_Perimeter(ST_Transform(geom,4326)::geography) AS perimeter_geog
FROM data;

 gid |  perimeter_geog
-----+------------------
   1 | 11439.2519522371
   2 | 5225.96374459924
(2 rows)
```

Answer (score 2):

If the geometry column was called 'wkb_geometry' on a table called 'counties' for instance, you could try...

```
select st_length(st_boundary(st_transform(wkb_geometry,2163))) as border_length from counties;
```

That assumes you are using data in the US; SRID 2163 seems to be a good one for measuring distance in meters.  You could choose a more appropriate one if you were dealing with a different area of the world.

Comment: The ares are small (~100m → 10km across) and are in Ireland, not the USA. What would be the best SRID to use?

Comment: Try 29903, The Irish Grid http://www.dnf.org/registry/coordinate_reference_systems/

Comment: @Rory or try `ST_Length(ST_Boundary(ST_Transform(geom,4326))::geography)`

Comment: @mike will changing to ::geography return the result in meters?

Comment: [yes](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_Length.html), that's part of the magic in the geography type.